# Unable to create a Directory in th mapped drive

Tags: visual-c++

I am unable to create a directory in a mapped drive. e.g. i have mapped U: to some location which there in the network. Using vc++ i am using CreateDirectory api, but it's not able to create directories. If i am giving any local machine location, it's creating. any solutions. Please let me know.

I have tried debugging my application, i find out that while running window service it's not creating but through debugging it's creating.

NOTE:
the location i want to create directory have full permissions.

Comment: What credentials is your service running under? Does the service's account have rights to the network? Can the service see the mapped drive? What happens if you use a UNC path instead?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the drive mapping to `U:` is not visible from your service. That's expected, since drive mappings are usually established per-user or per-session.

However, [CreateDirectory()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363855%28VS.85%29.aspx) supports [UNC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc227098%28PROT.10%29.aspx) paths, so you can pass `\\server\share\path` directly instead of using a mapped drive.